# Remove-Item giving error and not accepting path passed thru variable

Tags: powershell

Here is the code I am trying:

```
[string] $Server= "ServerName"
[string] $Database = "DBName"
$UserSqlQuery= $("select FileDelete from DBName.dbo.tmp_TableName")

# declaration not necessary, but good practice
$resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$resultsDataTable.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'FileDelete', ([string])))

$resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery
Write-Host ("The table contains: " + $resultsDatatable.Rows.Count + " rows")

echo $resultsDatatable
```

$RowDelete = $resultsDatatable

```
    foreach($RowDelete in $resultsDatatable)
    {
        echo "Inside For Loop"
        echo $RowDelete

        write-host “Deleting Duplicate PDF File/ Letter”;
    #   $RowDelete | foreach { $_.Delete()}
    #   $RowDelete | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-Item -recurse -force $RowDelete -erroraction silentlycontinue -Whatif

    }
```

DBName.dbo.tmp_TableName has single column with multiple values of path of the file on shared drive.

Example of Actual Path passed thru `$RowDelete` is `\\ccaintranet.com\Path\abc.pdf`.

The code is working without any error now. But it is not deleting the file from windows folder.

Can someone please help me to diagnose the error?

---

I removed SilentlyContinue option from above command and now I am seeing following error message -

Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Y:\Data\FS02-V\Aetna\ETL\DataLoads\RCE\System.Data.DataRow' because it does not exist. + Remove-Item <<<< -recurse -force $RowDelete -Whatif + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Y:\Data\FS02-V...em.Data.DataRow:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

It is getting the current path of the script and not accepting the path being Passed thru $RowDelete

Comment: You're missing code here. Somehow your variable $RowDelete is the parent directory joined with the object type and not the file name.

Comment: Can you please exlain further? Yes the error I am getting is due to it everytime getting parent directory of powershell script instead of path I am passing thru $RowDelete variable. When I try to print the variable value, it is showing me exact path.

Comment: Here are actual echo/ print statements before it gets to Remove-Item Inside For Loop
\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc\Data\FS02-V\Workspace\NishitShah\TestLetters\63566\1002059003.pdf                                                                                          
Deleting Duplicate PDF File/ Letter

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the right code.

Comment: Code is updated to reflect the details.

Comment: The code you say you're trying is missing a double quote in the first line. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, then copy/paste that exact code and error message.

Comment: I have updated the working code example. Code is not throwing any error now and runs with out any error but same time not deleting the actual files from the folder.

Comment: I removed SilentlyContinue option from above command and now I am seeing following error message - Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Y:\Data\FS02-V\Aetna\ETL\DataLoads\RCE\System.Data.DataRow' because it does not exist.

+             Remove-Item <<<<  -recurse -force $RowDelete -Whatif
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Y:\Data\FS02-V\...em.Data.DataRow:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Expected Result -
By running executing following query, $UserSqlQuery= $("select FileDelete from ServerName.DBName.dbo.tmp_TableName")
$resultsDataTable gets multiple rows. These are file names with the path in the format below - 
\\ccaintranet.com\Shared Server\Data\FS02-V\ClientName\Workspace\User\TestLetters\63566\1002059003.pdf

And what I am trying to achieve is deleting the above file using Remove-Item in PowerShell script.
Hope this information helps.